# Routing a custom domain name to a particular service when you have potentially 100K+ domains

Tags: kubernetes

Say you have a hosted blog SaaS product which 100K domains that route traffic to your SaaS product.

Customers point their domain names to your services ipaddress.

So there are multiple instances of your application that kubernetes manages, such that each instance has its own set of nginx, web servers and mysql database.

When an incoming request comes from one of those 100K domain names, you have to route the traffic to the correct instance of the application.

How would this be done using kubernetes?  Just trying to get a feel for what options are available or if this would be a custom code etc?

The domains could be mapped inside of redis, so a service could perform a lookup in redis that could tell you domain example1.com maps to instance 123.

Answer (score 2):

I would use DNS `IN CNAME` records instead of `IN A` or `IN AAAA` records. Then in nginx you can use [Server Blocks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/) to send the request to the right backend.